# if I were to click a button somewhere on a web page, I want specific text to appear in a specific form field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So for one of my classes I need to create a simple Web-App. In the index jsp page, I wanted to be able to click a button somewhere else in the page, causing this to automatically fill in a form field with a value, that would then be sent to the server.

So for example, if I clicked some button, I want text to fill in a search bar I created at the top of the page that reads "hello world" and also send that value to the server.

I am thinking I should be using Jquery's click() function. But I am unsure how to proceed from there.

Comment: Maybe the fact i wrote "for one of my classes" led you to think this, but this wasn't an implementation necessary for this assignment. The assignment was to become familiar with passing form data and communicating with the server. There's hundreds of resources online that dive into that. I asked that question because I wanted a unique manner for a user to fill in a search bar with a specific value. I wanted to go beyond the scope of the homework, because I find this interesting. That's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following maybe?

```
$("#button").click(function() {
  $("#input").val("My Text Here");
});
```

Of course you want to replace the selectors and text with what you actually want.

That basically says whenever a user clicks on `#button` set `#input` to `My Text Here`

`#input` being your text form field and `#button` being your button you want the user to click to display the text in the field.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed

Comment: @rahi901 Please mark it as correct if it helped you! :)